# regexp not working...arghhhh

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I'm using Flex 4. I'm driving myself crazy. Why won't the following work?

// in my Application tag:

```
creationComplete="replaceMe(event)"
```

// in my script block:

```
public function replaceMe(event:Event):void{
var str:String = "She sells seashells by the seashore.";
var pattern:RegExp = /sh/gi;
str.replace(pattern, "sch");
test.text = str;
}
```

my text area (id="test") says "She sells seashells by the seashore."...
it should say "sche sells seaschells by the seaschore."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because Strings are immutable objects. So, `str.replace()` just returns new string, without modifying `str`. Try

```
str = str.replace(pattern, "sch")
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign the new string value back to the old string like so:

```
str = str.replace(pattern, "sch");
```

**Edit:** Dzmitry answered first. =P